# How can I make a button within Google Sheets that toggles the values 1 and 0 in a destination cell?

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to learn to do basic buttons within a spreadsheet to help with a project at school. I am a simple teacher that is trying to find resources to help. I have learned how to create a button that adds one or subtracts one with the value which will allow me to do what I need to do, but ideally I am looking for script code to make a button that would toggle between the values of 1 and 0 upon pressing the button.

Thanks for any help.

```
function plus1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue() + 1
  );
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `a button that would toggle between the values of 1 and 0 upon pressing the button.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I think that when you provide the issue of your script and the sample input and output values you expect, it will help to think of your issue and solution. By the way, you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script?

Comment: I have created a button that when pressed will add +1 to cell A1 on Google Sheets with a script. I copied this from another site. I would like this script to instead of adding 1, just alternate values between 1 and 0. It would be like an if/then. If it is zero, I want to make the output 1 when pressed and if it is 1 I want to output 0.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't really even know what I am doing. I am just trying to get to where I can get it to do a simple task.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you add your current script to your question? If you can do, please add it by editing your question. By this, we can confirm your current situation from the script. About your goal, you want to switch the number of `1` and `0` by clicking a button. Is my understanding correct? By the way, you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script?

Comment: function plus1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue() + 1);
}

Comment: This is the script I copied and it works to add a value, but ideally I want one script to alternate values of 1 and 0. I believe Google Apps Script is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When the script is put to the comment, it becomes low readability. So I had proposed to add your script to your question. From `I believe Google Apps Script is correct.`, you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script. And I thought that I might understand your goal. So I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to switch the number of `1` and `0` at the cell "A1" on the active sheet by clicking a button.

In this case, at first, it is required to retrieve the value from the cell "A1" on the active sheet. And, the value is put by checking the retrieved value. So how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function sample() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1');
  var value = range.getValue();
  if (value == 1) {
    range.setValue(0);
  } else if (value == 0) {
    range.setValue(1);
  }
}
```

- In this case, when the cell "A1" is not `1` or `0`, the value in the cell is not modified.

#### References:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: @Benjamin Montgomery Thank you for replying. Can you test it in your environment? If that was not the result you expect, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: It is working in my environment. It is doing exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: @Benjamin Montgomery Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleActiveCell() {
  const sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  rg.setValue(rg.getValue()?0:1);
}

function toggleUniqueCell() {
   const sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(row,col);
  rg.setValue(rg.getValue()?0:1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you instead have a value -1 or +1 you can change it by multiplying with -1.
Then you have another column adding 1 to the result, dividing by two and round to integers, getting either 0 (for -1) or 1 (for +1).